# Making a table that sums the values of selected columns in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I wanted to make a table that shows the sum of particular column in each week. Take this data set for example:

```
Week     Customer   Business    Pleasure
1/1/2016     0          0           2
1/1/2016     3          0           2
1/8/2016     0          2           1
1/15/2016    4          2           3
1/15/2016    4          0           2
```

I wanted a table shows me the sum of all weeks for each column.
Can I use a table function?

Comment: Take a look at `?aggregate`

Comment: if my data set is defined as "data", then can my code look something like this?             table(data$week,colSums(week$Customer))